# Bind the data trigger of a GroupBox to the itemsource of its child control

Tags: wpf

I need to hide a GroupBox, if there is no data in ItemsSource of its child, which is an ItemsControl.

For eg. The ItemsControl will be bound to a collection(OptionalReads). The Ancestor of this ItemsControl is the GroupBox. I need to bind the visibility of this GroupBox to the count of the ItemSource of the ItemsControl.

What I tried and worked is the direct binding of OptionalReads.Count property as follows :-

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Header="Optional Reads" Template="{StaticResource GroupBoxTemplate}">
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OptionalReads.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="GroupBox.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
    <ItemsControl Name="OptionalReadItemsControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionalReads}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>.... </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
    </ItemsControl>
</GroupBox>
```

But What I need to do is to move this style as a common style and apply to various GroupBoxes having same structure.

I'm able to do this if we need to get the ItemsSource of a parent control and hide the GroupBox if there is no data in parent control, as follows :-

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ItemsSource.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
                      Value="0">
            <Setter Property="GroupBox.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but, how can we do the same concept in such a way to identify the child control dynamically and bind to the count of the ItemsSource of child control.

Comment: Why don't you implement a converter? You can make different checks not only for 0 but also for null or other options.

Answer (score 0):

The element hosted in a GroupBox as its content can be accessed at GroupBox.Content property. Thus you can reach the ItemsControl as follows.

```xml
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(GroupBox.Content).(ItemsControl.ItemsSource).Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="GroupBox.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"/>
</GroupBox>
```